# submitting the Form only once into database

Tags: php

```
 <?php
include("database.php");
include("session.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uploadpath = 'upload/'; // directory to store the uploaded files
$max_size = 2000; // maximum file size, in KiloBytes
$alwidth = 900; // maximum allowed width, in pixels
$alheight = 800; // maximum allowed height, in pixels
$allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpe', 'jpeg', 'png'); // allowed extensions
if(isset($_FILES['fileup']) && strlen($_FILES['fileup']['name']) > 1) {
$timestamp = time();
$uploadpath = $uploadpath . $timestamp . basename( $_FILES['fileup']['name']); // gets the file name
$sepext = explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['fileup']['name']));
$type = end($sepext); // gets extension
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']); // gets image width and height
$err = ''; // to store the errors
// Checks if the file has allowed type, size, width and height (for images)
if(!in_array($type, $allowtype)) $err .= 'The file: <b>'. $_FILES['fileup']['name']. '</b> not has the allowed extension type.';
if($_FILES['fileup']['size'] > $max_size*1000) $err .= '<br/>Maximum file size must be: '. $max_size. ' KB.';
if(isset($width) && isset($height) && ($width >= $alwidth || $height >= $alheight)) $err .= '<br/>The maximum Width x Height must be: '. $alwidth. ' x '. $alheight;
// If no errors, upload the image, else, output the errors
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name']))
{
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileup']['tmp_name'], $uploadpath) ;

$file=$uploadpath;
$caddress=$_POST["caddress"];
$username = $_SESSION["username"];

$result=mysql_query("insert into company(file,caddress,username)values('$file','$caddress','$username')");

echo "Inserted Successfully";
}
else
{
echo "There was an error uploading the data, please try again!";
}
}
}

?>
<center><b>Insert Company logo and Address</b></center><br>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" onSubmit="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<center><table style="width:250px">

<tr>
<td><b>Image</td> <td><input type="file" name="fileup" id="fileup" size="25" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b>Address</td>
<td><textarea name="caddress" maxlength="600" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></td></tr>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr>

</form
```

form should submit for the first time.if we submit from agian alert data already inserted.submitting the  Form only once into database.
form should submit for the first time.if we submit from agian alert data already inserted.submitting the  Form only once into database.

Answer (score 0):

use `headear` after submitting your `insert query` it will solve the isssue

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)//checking weather the query worked or not
{
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/congratz.html');
}

//You can give any file name there after Location does not matter
```

Check this link as well

Also mysql is deprecitaed, learn mysqli or PDO

For mysqli function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

For PDO function check this link http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And for learn about header check this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

disable the submit button on the click event

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it does this only partially. Your "soultion" will fail completely on browsers with disabled Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to avoid forms being submitted when, for instance, the "refresh" or "back" button are hit, the trick is to add a token to the form:

```
<?php
$msg = null;

session_start();
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    if( !isset($_POST['token'])
               ||!isset($_SESSION['formToken'])
               || $_POST['token'] !== $_SESSION['formToken']) {
        $msg = 'The form was not submitted.';
    } else {
        // do stuff
        $msg = 'The form was submitted successfully.';
    }
}

$formToken = uniqid('', true);
$_SESSION['formToken'] = $formToken;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if( $msg !== null) : ?>
        <p><?= $msg; ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <!-- stuff-->
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($formToken, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you reload a page, the same form input that was submitted is submitted again.

This means that if you add an input field with a unique ID (token), you can know that the same form would be submitted.

The values stored in a session variable will remain the same like a value stored in a file or database record, instead of reverting to the value it had when the form was submitted.

You can store the tokens in a session variable and compare it with the token submitted from the form. If they're not equal, this means that a form was submitted again and you can ignore the input (you'd prevent a database record insertion).

This also prevents form [spoofed form submissions](http://shiflett.org/articles/form-spoofing).